# Unable to load collection for the connection odata source in SSIS

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, ssis-2016

I am using SSIS to connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365(Version 9.0) WebApi to read the data. Below are the details.

- Control Name / Transformation(Source Component): OData Source
- OData Connection Manager:

  - Service Document Location: https://organizationname.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0
  - Authentication: Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online (with username and password)

After I entered above details and click "Test Connection", the connection is successful.

Now, when I dragged the OData Source Component and selected the OData connection, I am getting below error.

> Unable to load the collection for the connection OData source. The connection cannot open

Any pointers on how to fix this error?

Comment: Have a look at the Kingswaysoft tools for SSIS. They have a bunch of controls for CRM

Comment: Unfortunately, my organization does not allow to use any third party tools. So, I have to use the Dynamics CRM Online Web Api end point.

Answer (score 0):

Check your service document location.  This is the format we had to use to get it work:

`https:// [Your organization's root URL]/data`

Here's a link to Microsoft D365 and oData that was helpful on a similar project I worked on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata